3D Bin Packing problem with items distribution evenly constraints
I have a struggle with 3d bin packing problem that :

few types of items, weakly heterogeneous, but many items per type
Items can be only placed vertically and rotated 90 degree
only 1 type of container
Layer building
No compatibility constraints, weight constraints.
Especially, Items each type must be distributed as evenly as possible across used containers.

I used CLP Spreadsheet Solver built by Dr. Güneş Erdoğan,(https://www.euro-online.org/websites/verolog/clp-spreadsheet-solver-2/) it coded in VBA and I added snipped code that checks if the number of items type i in container j are over than max_item then do not load it in this container.
Max_item = int(Total number of items type i / number of available containers + 1 )
But it's not working properly
How do I solve this problem efficiently? Are there any other tools instead of VBA?
Solve item distribution constraints in 3d bin packing problem
